# How to display name from a subobject in a combobox?

Tags: wpf, oop, mvvm, combobox

I have a complex Article object with a list of Locations of type ArticleLocation. I need to display these locations in a combobox inside a GridView:

```
public class Article : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int sapNumber;
    private string descript;
    private ObservableCollection<ArticleLocation> locations;
    private ArticleLocation selectedLocation;


    public int SAPNumber
    {
        get => sapNumber;
        set
        {
            if (sapNumber != value)
            {
                sapNumber = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SAPNumber");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get => descript;
        set
        {
            if (descript == null || !descript.Equals(value))
            {
                descript = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }
    }

    internal ObservableCollection<ArticleLocation> Locations { get => locations; set => locations = value; }
    internal ArticleLocation SelectedLocation { get => selectedLocation; set => selectedLocation = value; }

}
```

I need to display the location stored like this:

```
class ArticleLocation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string location;
    private double available;

    public string Location { get => location; set => location = value; }
    public double Available { get => available; set => available = value; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

The combobox as I have it now:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" DisplayMemberPath="Location" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLocation}" SelectionChanged="RadComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

I dont know how to get the location to display so that it can be selected. The only alternative I can think of is to save the Location name and Available items in separate lists...

Not that it should make much of a difference but I am using telerik objects in the wpf form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the Locations and SelectedLocation properties were created as internal due to the ArticleLocation class not being public, and could thus not be accessed by the XAML view.

Changing the ArticleLocation class to public and the properties in my Article class to public they started showing in the comobox.

Answer (score 0):

Article class:

```
public class Article : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ArticleLocation> locations;
    public string Location { 
        get => location; 
        set
        {
            if (location == null || !location.Equals(value))
            {
                 location = value;
                 RaisePropertyChanged("Location");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ArticleLocation class:

```
public class ArticleLocation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string location;

    public string Location { 
        get => location; 
        set
        {
            if (location == null || !location.Equals(value))
            {
                location = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Location");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in your xaml.cs class:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Article article = new Article();
    this.DataContext = article;
}
```

Comment: Why do you change the DataContext to a new Article?
Also if you add a loose location property to Article it would lose the connected Available amount that I need, hence the SelectedLocation property.

Comment: You can change the DataContext to a ViewModel, just make sure the "Locations" and "Location" add RaisePropertyChanged event.